# C++ pure virtual method memory management question

Tags: c++, inheritance, memory-leaks, valgrind

I have a base class (`AClass` here) that has a `protected` resource (`str` here) that get's `free`'d in the `AClass` destructor. Derived `BClass` has a pure virtual `Init` method. Derived `CClass` implements `Init` which allocates some memory for the protected resource.

Valgrind is saying that I have 3 allocs and 2 frees. Honestly, I only **explicitly** see 1 alloc and 1 free, but I'll accept that there are some that I don't see (for now, but please someone explain). But, why aren't they **balanced** at least? Does every derived instance also have it's own `str` and it's not getting `free`'d?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

class AClass;
class BClass;
class CClass;

class AClass
{
public:
  AClass() : str(NULL) {
    printf("AClass Constructor with no params.\n");
    str = (char *) malloc(5 * sizeof(char)); 
  }
  AClass(char *foo) {
    printf("AClass Constructor with params, %s.\n", foo);
  }
  virtual ~AClass () {
    printf("AClass Destructor. Getting ready to free %s\n", str);
    free(str);
    printf("\tfree.\n");
  }

protected:
  char *str;
};

class BClass : public AClass
{
public:
  BClass() {
    printf("BClass Constructor with no params.\n");
  };
  BClass(char *foo) : AClass(foo) {
    printf("BClass Constructor with params, %s.\n", foo);
    str = foo;
  };
  virtual void Init() = 0;
  virtual ~BClass () {
    printf("BClass Destructor.\n");
  };
};

class CClass : public BClass
{
public:
  CClass () {
    printf("CClass Constructor with no params.\n");
  };
  void Init() {
    printf("CClass Init method.\n");
    str = (char *) malloc(255 * sizeof(char));
    printf("\tmalloc.\n");
    snprintf(str, 255 * sizeof(char), "Hello, world.");
  };
  virtual ~CClass () {
    printf("CClass Destructor.\n");
  };
};

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  printf("Start.\n");
  BClass *x = new CClass();
  x->Init();
  delete x;
  printf("End.\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Here's the Valgrind output.

```
==6641== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6641== Copyright (C) 2002-2009, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6641== Using Valgrind-3.6.0.SVN-Debian and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6641== Command: ./a.out
==6641==
Start.
AClass Constructor with no params.
BClass Constructor with no params.
CClass Constructor with no params.
CClass Init method.
        malloc.
CClass Destructor.
BClass Destructor.
AClass Destructor. Getting ready to free Hello, world.
        free.
End.
==6641==
==6641== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6641==     in use at exit: 5 bytes in 1 blocks
==6641==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 2 frees, 268 bytes allocated
==6641==
==6641== LEAK SUMMARY:
==6641==    definitely lost: 5 bytes in 1 blocks
==6641==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6641==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6641==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6641==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6641== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==6641==
==6641== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6641== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 18 from 7)
```

Comment: And what happpens when you turn  on `--leak-check=full` option?

Comment: sort of unrelated, but is there a reason you're using char* instead of std::string?

Comment: You have a `malloc` in the constructor of `AClass`. Why aren't you doing `printf("\tmalloc.\n")` for that `malloc` as well? That's the reason you can't see your unbalanced `malloc` in the output of your program.

Comment: Also, what "every derived instance" are you talking about when you have only one class instance in your entire program?

Comment: @MahlerFive, being sort of new to C++ and not having any other C++ developers around, I turned to Google's C++ styleguide (http://bit.ly/eMAtAy). I, too, have my doubts about their call on this one and I'd love to discuss it in a different forum if you want.

Comment: @AndreyT Thanks for pointing out that I wasn't logging that other malloc. I will do that. I either overlooked it because I didn't think that constructor was getting called -- or I just forgot!

Comment: @AndreyT Also, when I said "Does every derived instance also have it's own str and it's not getting free'd?" I meant, for a given instance of class C, is there a respective copy of the 'str' resource associated with each parent in the hierarchy? Thanks for asking me to clarify. My original question was horribly worded. And also, I'm pretty sure I know the answer to be "no," but I was just reaching for straws.

Comment: @Jason edit your question to clarify if you feel it is poorly worded. I also echo @MahlerFive's comment about using std::string instead of a dynamically allocated array or characters, it will make your life easier.

Comment: Google's style guide is good for maintaining their old code base, not a general recommendation for writing new code. The double init of classes causes extra problems, like you have just seen. If you can do all the initialization is the constructors, that usually works much better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you construct and then `Init` an instance of your `CClass`, the `str` pointer is first assigned a pointer from the `malloc` call in the `AClass` default constructor, and then later assigned a pointer from the `malloc` call in `CClass::Init`.  The memory allocated in the `AClass` default constructor is never freed, and the pointer is lost when `str` is overwritten in `CClass::Init`.

You could check for a non-NULL value in the `str` pointer before re-assigning it in `CClass::Init`.  Alternatively, you could encapsulate `str` assignment in a member function that performs this check, so that this concern doesn't arise elsewhere:

```
void allocate_str(int size) {
   if (str) free(str);
   str = (char*) malloc(size * sizeof(char));
}
```

Better yet, you could make use of the C++ run-time library's many modern features, including string objects and smart pointers.

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't really have anything to do with virtual functions.
Three allocations that Valgrind detects are:

1. `new CClass` in `main`.
2. `malloc` in `AClass` constructor.
3. `malloc` in `CClass::Init`.

As to why the calls aren't balanced: you're leaking `str` that's alloc'd in `AClass` constructor — you're changing `str` pointer in `CClass::Init`:

```
void Init() {
    // ...
    str = (char *) malloc(255 * sizeof(char));
    // ...
};
```

without first freeing the previously allocated buffer.

Comment: Thank you for listing out the 3 allocs explicitly. I guess I could have figured that out via some extra command-line switch on Valgrind, but I'm still learning how to interpret it's output.

Answer (score 2):

The AClass default constructor has this line:

```
 str = (char *) malloc(5 * sizeof(char)); // hey, 5 bytes!
```

In your Init, you lose it when you do this

```
 str = (char *) malloc(255 * sizeof(char));
```

The third alloc (and second free) is the new and delete of CClass